# Connecting Oracle database in C++

Tags: c++, database, oracle, c++11

I'm looking for API to develop C++ app which will be connecting with Oracle database. While looking through internet I found OCILIB.

Do you know any better solution or should I use OCILIB? I'm looking for new technologies and don't know if OCILIB is deprecated.

Don't know if it matter, but app will use only SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT statements.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conencting to the Oracle databse, Oracle provides an API:
[Oracle Call interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/toc.htm)

It is needed by all libraries which are a wrapper to it.

[cpprefrence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs) provides links to the following databse related libraries:

- OTL
- DTL
- libpqxx
- lmdb++ -  C++11 wrapper for the LMDB embedded B+ tree database library.
- mongocxx -  C++11 driver library for MongoDB
- mysql++
- ODB - C++ Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)
- QUINCE: QUeries IN C++ Expressions (ORM+EDSL)
- QxOrm - C++ Qt Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)
- SOCI
- sqlpp11